# tableview indexing confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating simple reveal menu in my demo application. Right now what I am doing is I have a one MutableArray named `MutableMenu`

```
NSArray menu = [@"menu1",@"Menu2","Menu3",@"Menu4"];
MutableMenu = [NSMutableArray alloc]initwithArray:menu];
```

I am just displaying this mutable array in my by default tableview cell.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am using static indexing like below code snippet

```
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_TO_MANAGE_TASK sender:nil];
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_TO_MANAGE_LEAVE sender:nil];
    }
```

All is working great till now. Now I have a array that I want to check permission to display in tableview cell. For example first user have only 2 permissions from 4 menus. This user only able to access menu1 and menu2. Likewise different users different permissions.
This is my code to maintaining this scenario in `viewDidLoad`. All is working fine

```
BOOL permisson = NO;
NSArray *Roles = [USERDEFAULT objectForKey:PREF_ROLE_ARRAY];
for (NSString *temp in Roles) {
    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"55"] || [temp isEqualToString:@"45"] || [temp isEqualToString:@"67"] ) {
        permisson = YES;
        if ([Mutablemenu containsObject:@"Team management"])
            NSLog(@"Already Have");
        else [Mutablemenu insertObject:@"Team management" atIndex:2];
      }
}
if (!permisson) {
    [Mutablemenu removeObject:@"Team management"];
    [Mutablemenu insertObject:@"" atIndex:2];
    [MutableImages removeObject:@"team.png"];
}
[_tableview reloadData];
```

All is working fine But when user have only 3 permission.My indexing is changed in `didSelectRowatIndexPath`. For Example first user have 4 permission then index is 0,1,2,3 but when user have 3 permission then index is 0,1,2.

But my question is how do I handle this situation in `didSelectRowatIndexPath`. Because every time indexing is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by @RJV Kumar, you should have check actual menu clicked instead of `indexPath` in `didSelectRowatIndexPath` as:

```
if([menuArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString: @"Menu1"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_TO_HANDLE_MENU_1 sender:nil];
}
else if([menuArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString: @"Menu2"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_TO_HANDLE_MENU_2 sender:nil];
}
.
.
so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are finding the menu based on **index**, but you should not do like that,

instead of that maintain **menuid or menuname** to identify which menu the user selected. By this way, you don't have to worry about the index.

In **didselectRow method**, by comparing **menuid or menuname**, do your operation